# IO and Maybe monad interaction

Tags: haskell

I have the following code but I feel it is too ugly and imperative.  Would anybody rephrase it to be more functional?   (I messed with MaybeT but could not make it work)  Applicative answers welcome as well.

```
getString :: IO String

pred :: String -> Bool

f :: String -> String

result :: IO (Maybe String)
result = do
  s <- getString
  if pred s
    then return $ Just $ f s
    else return Nothing
```

EDIT: A follow-up question: what if both pred and f also return results within IO (should I split this out into a separate question?)

```
getString :: IO String

pred :: String -> IO Bool

f :: String -> IO String

result :: IO (Maybe String)
result = do
  s <- getString
  b <- pred s
  if b
    then Just <$> f s
    else return Nothing
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I would begin by taking the logic here out of the `IO` monad. Your function can then be written as

```
result :: IO (Maybe String)
result = foo <$> getString

foo :: String -> Maybe String
foo s | pred s    = Just (f s)
      | otherwise = Nothing
```

You could probably write `foo` in different ways using some fancy combinators, but I don't think that's necessary here. The most important thing is to get your logic out of `IO` so that it's easier to test.

Comment: +1 It can't be denied that getting the logic out of `IO` is more important than having a fancy one-line solution.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a nice little combinator:

```
ensure :: MonadPlus m => (a -> Bool) -> (a -> m a)
ensure p x = guard (p x) >> return x
```

Now we can write a pure function which checks your predicate and applies `f` when appropriate:

```
process :: String -> Maybe String
process = fmap f . ensure pred
```

Lifting this to an `IO` action is simply another `fmap`:

```
result = fmap process getString
```

Personally, I'd probably inline `process`, and write that this way instead:

```
result = fmap (fmap f . ensure pred) getString
```

...which is a relatively clean description of what's happening.

Answer (score 9):

The obvious transformation from your code is to factor the `return` operations:

```
result = do
  s <- getString
  return $ if pred s
           then Just (f s)
           else Nothing
```

This makes the pattern more apparent:

```
result = liftM g getString
g s | pred s    = Just (f s)
    | otherwise = Nothing
```

By applying `f` from outside, we can make the next pattern apparent:

```
g s = liftM f $ if pred s then Just s else Nothing
```

Which lets us remplace the `if` block:

```
g = liftM f . mfilter pred . return
```

Summing it up:

```
result = liftM (liftM f . mfilter pred . return) getString
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import Control.Monad

result = getString >>= (return . fmap f . (mfilter pred . Just) )
```

Comment: Notice that `mfilter` replaces your if-then-else.

Comment: `result = (f <$> mfilter pred . Just) <$> getString`

Comment: @FUZxxl that doesn't type check.  `mfilter pred . Just :: a -> Maybe a`, but `f <$> x` is expecting `x :: Maybe a`.  You need some sort of applicative composition operator `f <.> g = \x -> f <$> g x`, which if given lower precedence than `.` allows `result = (f <.> mfilter pred . Just) <$> getString`.  Also, replacing `Just` with `return` allows any `Monad` to be used.

Comment: How about `result = (fmap f . mfilter pred . return) <$> getString`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't easily get away with the clunky `if-then-else`, but you can get away with the redundant `returns`:

```
import Control.Monad

result :: IO (Maybe String)
result = go <$> getString where
  go s | pred s    = Just $ f s
       | otherwise = Nothing
```